# Karate framework: how to reuse variable used in one sceario to be called in another without declaring it as global variables

Tags: java, karate

Requirement to use a variable defined a scenario should be called in another scenario which cannot be accomplished by karateconfig.js or by initiating it in background Please suggest how can we accomplish this

```
featurefile1.feature
 feature: sample feature 1
@tag1
scenario: sample scenario 1
* def filename = 'sample file.txt'
* print filename

featurefile2.feature
feature: sample feature 2
Scenario: sample scenario 2
* def  filename1 = call read (featurefile1.feature@tag1)  
* print filename1

the result of feature file2 should be samplefilet.txt
```

Comment: it can be acheived by

print filename1.filename

all the variables defined in scenario can be called call read (featurefile1.feature@tag1)